# my HTML Form Using PHP and MySQL is not working

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to create a simple html form that hold the information via MySQL however I am having some problem connecting to the database. I think $db_selected = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $link); is giving me the problem. FYI DB_NAME is the database table I want to use.

My HTML

```
<form action="demo.php" method="post">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="firstname">First Name:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstname" name="first_name">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="lastname">Last Name:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastname" name="last_name">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="dob">Date of birth:</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="dob" name="date_of_birth">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="pob">Place of birth:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="pob" name="place_of_birth">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="government">Your Local government:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="government" name="government">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="qualifications">Qualifications:</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="qualifications" name="qualifications"></textarea>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="skills">Skills:</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="skills" name="skills"></textarea>
          </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
        </form>
```

My PHP

```
<?php

define('DB_NAME', 'forms1');
define('DB_USER', 'c88888');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '*******');
define('DB_HOST', 's********.com');

$link = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);


$db_selected = mysqli_select_db(DB_NAME, $link);

if (!$db_selected) {
    die('Can\'t use ' . DB_NAME . ': ' . mysqli_error());
}

$value = $_POST['first_name'];
$value2 = $_POST['last_name'];
$value3 = $_POST['date_of_birth'];
$value4 = $_POST['place_of_birth'];
$value5 = $_POST['government'];
$value6 = $_POST['qualifications'];
$value7 = $_POST['skills'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO demo (first_name, last_name, date_of_birth, place_of_birth, government, qualifications, skills) VALUES ('$value', '$value2', '$value3', '$value4', '$value5', '$value6', '$value7')";

if (!mysqli_query($sql)) {
    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error());
}

mysqli_close();
?>
```

Comment: You should use mysqli everywhere, not mysql

Comment: first_name != firstname they have to match

Comment: @user2182349 I have change the code still does'nt work

Comment: @nogad thanks but it still does not fix the problem

Comment: update with the new code

Comment: @nogad I have sorry

Comment: Bing Bang Boe... Keep in mind that this script is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: I'd also suggest you also have to kill off the habit of giving things uselessly generic names like `$value1`. This is a bad anti-pattern.

Comment: @tadman but that's how I was told how to do it on the Youtube tutorials

Comment: @M.S.P I am not going to put this online for people to see I just want to learn how to use php with sql

Comment: Stop watching those YouTube tutorials before you hurt yourself. Many of them are produced by people with almost no idea of what they're doing, it's the blind leading the blind. If you want better advice, [PHP the Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) is a good place to start.

Comment: @tadman ok thanks but it does not really help my question

Comment: Does your database exist? What specific error are you getting?

Comment: yeah the database exist  the error I get is "Can't use forms1:"

Answer (score 1):

Just change your code where you have db_selected to:

```
$db_selected = mysqli_select_db($link, DB_NAME);
```

And make sure you escape your values before entering them into database by using prepared statements or `mysqli_real_escape_string()` and its better to write your values with brackets like `('{$value1}', '{$value2'})`

Answer (score 1):

Try giving DB_HOST to "localhost", because almost every server stores their database in localhost itself. Try below code to connect to your database and also make sure to give the right database name.

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

define('DB_NAME', 'name');
define('DB_USER', 'user');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '****');
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

$dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

if(!$dbc){
   die('could not connect: ' .mysql_error());
}

?>
```

Answer (score -2):

When writting your SQL query as a string, separate the database fields using backticks (`).

You're using `'$value'` inside a single quote, which means PHP understands that as a literal `$value` value, instead of a variable.

You should change query to:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `demo` (`first_name`, `last_name`, `date_of_birth`, `place_of_birth`, `government`, `qualifications`, `skills`)
        VALUES ('" . $value . "', '" . $value2 . "', '" . $value3 . "', '" . $value4 . "', '" . $value5 . "' , '" . $value6 . "', '" . $value7 . "')";
```

Comment: Befor change your query echo variables for checking value to make sure your problem is not from form side